# Rupee symbol not working

Tags: html, currency, symbols

We have a content management system from which we fetch the rupee symbol (₹) set in settings to show product price in Indian Rupees. We are not able to use HTML code for rupee (₹) where this setting is done. On some machines it renders correctly, but on couple of machines, the symbol is getting rendered as a box. I have also added the unicode meta tag to my HTML, but doesn't work.

Could anyone please provide solution to this?

Comment: Also, are you letting the browser use default fonts? As the fonts will change for different browsers/OS etc, and sometime the character for some symbols isn't available. As answered below, use Font Awesome, as it works across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Font awesome is having the rupee icon. You can use it as fonts. have a look on this link: http://fontawesome.io/icons/#currency

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guys, I got this working using open google fonts.  Used this font for the section where price was rendered: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Hind

Apparently it was a windows 7 issue which doesn't render the symbol correctly because of the unavailability of correct font.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the head of your HTML-file? Which charset do you use?

Did you try it with the numeric char: `&#8377;` in your HTML?

Otherwise - I know, it's not the best idea - you do a screenshot from the rupee sign and embed it as an image.

Comment: The poster did say they are not able to enter HTML character code for the setting...

Comment: The problem is we cant use HTML code at the place where we assign this currency symbol, screenshot also will not work with current system. The placeholder is dynamic where currency symbol and price gets pulled from backend